# Cannot find module 'typescript' error while running ng build (tsc version 4.2.9 is installed)

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, ng

I have angular 16, node 18 and typescript 4.2.9 installed on my MacBook. But whenever I do ng build, I get the error `An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module 'typescript'`.

**Error Message:**

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module 'typescript'
Require stack:
- /Users/matrix/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/plugin.js
- /Users/matrix/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js
- /Users/matrix/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js
- /Users/matrix/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/tools/webpack/configs/common.js
- /Users/matrix/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/tools/webpack/configs/index.js
- /Users/matrix/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/builders/browser/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/node-modules-architect-host.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/build-impl.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/export-ref.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/json-schema.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/cli/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/init.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
See "/private/var/folders/25/fqqpwxhd77n5n0c12bbzqgdm0000gn/T/ng-mrzREo/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

**Log file:**

```
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:833:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1051:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/vaayu/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/plugin.js:35:25)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1203:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1027:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:868:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1051:19)
```

**Angular and Node Versions:**

```
Angular CLI: 10.2.0
Node: 18.10.0
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 16.2.8
... core, localize, platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                          Version
----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect        0.1602.5
@angular-devkit/core             16.2.5
@angular-devkit/schematics       16.2.5
@angular-devkit/schematics-cli   16.2.5
@schematics/angular              16.2.5
@schematics/update               0.1002.0 (cli-only)
rxjs                             7.8.1
typescript                       4.9.5
```

**Typescript version**

```
(base) ➜  ClientApp git:(18-add-question-creation-page) ✗ tsc -v
Version 4.9.5
(base) ➜  ClientApp git:(18-add-question-creation-page) ✗
```

Comment: Looks like you have installed the typescript compiler globally. Does the error occurr if you install tsc locally for this specific project? i.e `npm i typescript@4.9.5` instead of `npm i -g typescript@4.9.5`

Comment: @EdgarP-Yan I have tried both ways. The error still occurs when I install it locally.